# Sorting for maximum mean squared successive difference

Tags: optimization, algorithms, proof-writing, permutations

I have a set of numbers and I have to order them for maximum MSSD (mean squared successive difference). For example, if I have the ordered set 
{1,2,3,4,5,6}
this would give me an MSSD of 
MSSD=$\frac{1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2}{5}=\frac{5}{5}=1$
This is obviously not the best order. The maximum is reached at 
{3,5,1,6,2,4} 
Here one has 
MSSD=$\frac{2^2+4^2+5^2+4^2+2^2}{5}$.

I have a simple heuristic in mind for this problem. Start with an empty set and then always add the elements that will enlarge the sum of squared differences the most. With this example it would give the following:
Start with empty set 
 {}
Then add 1 and 6 (this adds $5^2$):
{1,6}
then add 5 (this adds $4^2$)
{5,1,6} 
then 2 (also adds $4^2$): 
{5,1,6,2} 
and then 3 and 4 (both add $2^2$): 
{3,5,1,6,2,4}

Because we are using squared differences, bigger differences are more important, contribute more to the MSSD and should be prioritized. Using simulations, this simple algorithm indeed always gives the best solution. Moreover this solution seems to be unique (except for the reverse order, which is the following in the example:
{4,2,6,1,5,3},
which obviously gives the same result). However, I can't proof this. Is this a known problem? Can somebody help me to proof that this heuristic gives indeed the optimal order?

Thanks!

Comment: These are not sets, but lists. A set is unordered